# Deployment of ADF Mobile incomplete

Tags: java, mobile, deployment, oracle-adf

I'm trying to deploy ADF Mobile to the Android emulator from JDeveloper but this always results in an error. The messages are:

```
[08:53:37 AM] Creating AndroidManifest.xml file...

[08:53:38 AM] Creating unsigned Android application file...

[08:56:25 AM] Compiling Android Resource Identifier file...

[08:56:55 AM] Creating Android classes.dex file from class files...

[08:56:55 AM] Command-line executed:  "D:\AndroidSDK\sdk\platform-tools\dx.bat" --dex --debug --keep-classes --output="C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\classes.dex" C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\classes C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\framework\build\jar\AND_ksoap.jar C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\framework\build\jar\Container.jar C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\framework\build\jar\IDMMobileSDK.jar C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\framework\build\jar\logging_dalvik_release.jar C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\framework\build\jar\phonegap.jar C:\JDeveloper\mywork\TestMobile\deploy\ANDROID_MOBILE_NATIVE_archive2\framework\build\jar\vmchannel_dalvik_release.jar

[08:56:55 AM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...

[08:56:56 AM] Deployment cancelled.

[08:56:56 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.

[08:56:56 AM] Argument has embedded quote, use the explicit CMD.EXE call.
```